# How to solve androidx.test.tools.crawler.SignaturePatchingCallback@3abe0b8 stage: PRE_ON_CREATE)

Tags: android, automated-tests

I want to use App crawler to test my app, but I got the following error after I execute this command  `java -jar crawl_launcher.jar --app-package-name com.**.*** --android-sdk ~/Library/Android/sdk --ui-automator-mode`

```
2022-04-15 01:09:45.555 29636-29636/androidx.test.tools.crawler.stubapp E/ApplicationLifecycleMonitorImpl: Callback threw exception! (callback: androidx.test.tools.crawler.SignaturePatchingCallback@3abe0b8 stage: PRE_ON_CREATE)
    java.lang.NullPointerException
        at java.io.Reader.<init>(Reader.java:78)
        at java.io.InputStreamReader.<init>(InputStreamReader.java:72)
        at androidx.test.tools.crawler.SignaturePatchingCallback.readSignatures(SignaturePatchingCallback.java:22)
        at androidx.test.tools.crawler.SignaturePatchingCallback.enableSignaturePatching(SignaturePatchingCallback.java:5)
        at androidx.test.tools.crawler.SignaturePatchingCallback.onApplicationLifecycleChanged(SignaturePatchingCallback.java:3)
        at androidx.test.internal.runner.lifecycle.ApplicationLifecycleMonitorImpl.a(ApplicationLifecycleMonitorImpl.java:24)
        at androidx.test.runner.MonitoringInstrumentation.callApplicationOnCreate(MonitoringInstrumentation.java:120)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.handleBindApplication(ActivityThread.java:6725)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.access$1500(ActivityThread.java:247)
        at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:2053)
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:106)
        at android.os.Looper.loopOnce(Looper.java:201)
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:288)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:7839)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
        at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:548)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1003)
```